# Create answer file for bash script

Tags: linux, bash

I would like to create an answer file for somebody elses bash script. When you run the bash script, you are asked 5 questions the first time you install the software.

I used the `yes | ./script` command and it works, it automatically answers `yes` to all of the questions. However, I would like to answer `no` for the last question. Is there a way to answer `yes` to the first 4 questions, and `no` to the fifth?

Answer (score 4):

provide your answers in this way or from a file directly to `stdin`

```
./script << EOF
yes
yes
yes
yes
no
EOF
```

(use `y` or `yes` depending on what your script will expect - probably just "`y`" and "`n`" will be enough since `yes` program works).

For more complex tasks you may eventually consider using something like [Expect](http://expect.sourceforge.net/) ([wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect))

Answer (score 1):

This basic trick may work in your case:

```
echo -e "y\ny\ny\ny\nn"          | ./script
```

or

```
echo -e "yes\nyes\nyes\nyes\nno" | ./script
```

but it depends on how your script handles the input stream...

Answer (score 0):

```
{ yes yes | sed 4q; yes no | sed 1q; } | ./script  # or just "echo no"
```

or

```
yes yes | sed -e 5s/yes/no/ -e 5q
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while ((++c<5)); do echo "y"; done ; echo "n" | ./script
```