# Powershell answer file similar to Linux bash

Tags: powershell

What I want: Execute my powershell script (.ps1) and answer all the read-host questions using an answer file.

On Linux bash this is straightforward see:[Answer file Linux bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17725345/create-answer-file-for-bash-script)

Comment: Why not just modify the script to read your answer file if it exists, prompt if the file doesn't?  Seems like a more elegant solution.

Comment: The script is mostly used interactively by answering read-host questions on the command line. For testing and repetitive tasks it is very useful to have the option to answer the questions with an answer file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are asking for does not exist in PowerShell, the methods of passing arguments to a function (e.g. [splatting](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/JJ672955.aspx), the [pipeline](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Hh847902.aspx)) cannot be used with Read-Host.

What is possible is creating your script as a [function](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Hh847829.aspx) and making use of the aforementioned methods to pass the arguments when the function is to be run in an automated fashion.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a subexpression (`$()`) to call `Read-Host` in case a parameter argument is not present:

```
param(
    $Name = $(Read-Host -Prompt "Input Name"),
    $Company = $(Read-Host -Prompt "Input Company Name"),
    $Country = $(Read-Host -Prompt "Country")
)

if(-not $Country){
    $Country = "US"
}

Write-Host $(@'
Hello, {0} from {1}!

How is the weather in {2}?
'@ -f $Name,$Company,$Country)

# do more stuff
```

Save as `myscript.ps1`.

Now, when you run it without any parameters, it prompts you for all the values:

```
PS C:\> .\prompt.ps1
Input Name: Arni
Input Company Name: MegaCorp Inc.
Country:
Hello, Arni from MegaCorp Inc.!

How is the weather in US?
PS C:\>
```

But if you want to run it without being prompted, just supply all required parameters:

```
PS C:\> .\prompt.ps1 -Name Xavier -Company "SuperCorp SA" -Country Brazil
Hello, Xavier from SuperCorp SA!

How is the weather in Brazil?
PS C:\>
```